# Is it haram to wear a Remembrance Day Poppy?

Tags: halal-haram, clothing

In the UK, [Remembrance Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remembrance_Day) is a day which one pays respect to soldiers who died in the two world wars and others. In the weeks leading up to this day, it is customary to wear a [(fake) poppy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remembrance_poppy) on one's shirt as a sign of respect.

Is it haram to do this? I know some Muslims say it is haram because it "celebrates the killing of Muslims". Personal opinions aside, is it actually haram? And, if so, why?

Comment: Don't forget there are many Muslims who served in the British Armed Forces throughout history. You are remembering them as well.

Comment: Why would a Muslim wear this poppy?

Comment: Those soldiers fought for `someone` and thus you need to know intentions of all those `someone`s in fighting those wars. In Islam, killing of an innocent human being is like killing the humankind. Instead of remembering those soldiers, why not condemn those `someone`s and expose their game-plan of controlling the world!!! In UK, they are not condemning, but just remembering because UK was (and is) herself one of those `someone`s

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The criteria for clothing that is relevant to this situation is that a Muslim is not allowed to wear anything that is a religious symbol of another nation. E.g. Wearing a cross.

Since the poppy leaf at this time does not relate to any other religion, it is perfectly fine to wear it.

Comment: `poppy leaf at this time does not relate to any other religion`. This is not that simple, there is a history associated with it and you need to know and understand that history.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add World War I involved Britain fighting the Muslim Ottoman Empire in which many Muslims lost their lives and ended in the allied powers colonizing the Muslim lands largely thanks to the secret Sykes-Picot Agreement.

In this secret agreement Britain was rewarded with Palestine and as you are all aware of the Balfour Declaration in 1917 which is a direct result of this war.

In relation to the Muslim soldiers who died they were mainly recruited because Britain was in control of the colonized regions of India so in reality did not join this war voluntarily.

I am not saying it's haram but I would not recommend this.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from Wikipedia ([revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Remembrance_Day&oldid=579239658)):

> Remembrance Day is observed on 11 November to recall the end of
>   hostilities of World War I on that date in 1918.

Therefore it doesn't seems to have anything to do with celebrating the killing of Muslims and hence logically it shouldn't be deemed haram.

Comment: What about its political implications? Sympathizing with British government which was responsible in the greatest carnage of the 20th century!

Comment: I don't think that comes into the domain of halal and haram. Maybe the domain consciousness and ethics.